# how can I remove lines from file using command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, sed, cmd

how can i delete part of the file with command line?

I have tried using sed the following way:

```
c:\sed '1,2!d' res.txt > res.txt
```

but the file became empty

what i exepect to get is

```
  1 a
  2 b
  3 c
  4 d
```

to become

```
 1 a
 2 b
```

in the same file res.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to call `c:\sed '1,2!d' res.txt`. You'll see correct result:

```
  1 a
  2 b
```

So, you can't use the same file for input and output. You can use different files and move/copy after it: `c:\sed '1,2!d' res.txt > res.tmp & move /y res.tmp res.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Add `-i` or `--in-place` switch to sed to read and write the same file. Also, windows command line uses double quotes. So you should use

```
sed -i "1,2!d" res.txt
```

Comment: it does not seems to work on my win xp, won't recognize -i or --in-place option

Comment: @adam, silly question but, have you installed `sed`? it is not a native windows utility. The answer is adjusted to the question in the usage of `sed`.

Comment: @MC_ND, i have not installed anything, but i can use sed without -i option

Comment: @adam, in my case, both the gnuwin32 and the mingw versions of sed (4.2.1) allow the usage of `-i` or `--in-place` switches. But the sed version from unixutils (3.02) does not include it.

Comment: @adam, `sed` is not included in a clean windows install. Have you installed `Windows Services for Unix`?

Comment: @adam, well, `sed` was installed from somewhere. If you can, update it to a newer version. If you can not update it, use a temporary file as pointed by Ilya in its answer. It can be done without a temporary file using a `for /f` command, but is less efficient.